# jquery for server controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this jQuery function which works with HTML controls

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydropdown').change(function(){
            $selected_value=$('#mydropdown option:selected').text();
            $('#result').text($selected_value);
        });
    });
```

However, if I want to use it with ASP.NET server controls, the second line would change to

`$('#<%=mydropdown.ClientID%>').change(function(){`

So, my question is, how do I modify this line so that it works

```
$selected_value=$('#mydropdown option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dropdown is server side component. .NET will append certain value with your ID.

You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your control to make the generated IDs consistent

For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="mydropdown" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="True"  runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Value 1"> Value 1 </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Value 2"> Value 2 </asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you make `ClientIDMode` it will not append any value to your dropdown's id and you can use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydropdown').change(function() {
        $selected_value = $('#mydropdown option:selected').text();
        $('#result').text($selected_value);
    });
});
```

Or

if your `$('#<%=mydropdown.ClientID%>').change(function(){` is working as expected then you can simply change your jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=mydropdown.ClientID%>').change(function() {
        $selected_value = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $('#result').text($selected_value);
    });
});
```

Here `$(this)` is the dropdown which you are changing.

Comment: Thank you, works now. Just one more thing, will setting the `ClientIDMode` to static have any repercussions?

Comment: Hi @fasih I have updated jquery as well. For more details on `ClientIDMode` you can find it in msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: +1 for this

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=mydropdown.ClientID%>').change(function() {
        $selected_value = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $('#result').text($selected_value);
    });
});`

Comment: @fasih Thank you :)